# jOptionPane returns 0 values instead of decent computational result

Tags: java, joptionpane

**pay.java**

```
public class Pay{
//Data members- private

    private double basicHours, otHours, basicRate; // setters
    private double basicPay, otPay, totalPay; //getters

//constartor

    public Pay(){

    }

// Setters - setting the volues from main class

    public void setBasicHours (double basicHours){
        this.basicHours = basicHours;

    }

    public void setOtHours (double otHours){
            this.otHours = otHours;

    }

    public void setBasicRate (double basisRate){
            this.basicRate = basicRate;

    }

// compute method

        public void computePay(){
            basicPay = basicHours * basicRate;
            otPay = otHours * basicRate * 1.5;
            totalPay = basicPay +otPay;
     }

// getters - returning the values to the main class

            public double getBasicPay(){
                return basicPay;

    }

            public double getOtPay(){
                return otPay;

    }

            public double getTotalPay(){
                return totalPay;

    }
    } // class
```

**payApp.java**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PayApp{
    public static void main(String args[]){

// Declare Variables

        double basicHours, otHours, basicRate;
        double basicPay, otPay, totalPay;

// Declare and create object
        Pay myP = new Pay();

//Input
        basicHours = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the basic hours"));
        otHours = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the overtime hours"));
        basicRate = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the basic rate"));

//Process call setter compute and getters

    myP.setBasicHours(basicHours);
    myP.setOtHours(otHours);
    myP.setBasicRate(basicRate);

    myP.computePay();

    basicPay = myP.getBasicPay();
    otPay = myP.getOtPay();
    totalPay = myP.getTotalPay();


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Basic Pay: " + basicPay + "\n OTPay; " + otPay + "\n Total Pay;" + totalPay);


    } // main
}// class
```

both files are compiling without errors but when users enters volumes for computations it give only zeros back

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems on how to use a debugger to find such errors.

Comment: This is sorted guys. Thanks!